# Storing/retrieving highly dynamic data from an Android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to develop an Android app to help me test ceramic glazes, and have run into a problem with storing data. The main feature I want is, within one glaze, the ability to modify its recipe, yet still keep the older versions of that recipe. Since a lot of my data is repetitive (finish, opacity, firing atmosphere, etc.), a database would be the best way to store that data. However, each glaze can have any number of versions, and the recipe within each version can have any number of ingredients (normally 1-10, but as much as 20). I cannot think of a way to store and retrieve this "two dimensional" dynamic data. I could make an individual database for each glaze, but I feel that defeats the purpose of a database. Any help implementing a way to store this highly dynamic data would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't want to store unnecessary data, but that sounds like the best way to go about this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to have a number of related tables.

I'd suggest a glaze base table, containing the base glazes, a table for recipe/versioned glazes. An ingredients/properties table. An then an extended link/associative table table this being used to link ingredients properties to recipes and also contain amounts.

The **Glaze** Table would be very simple just the name of the glaze and a unique identifier. e.g
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS glazes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, glazename TEXT)`

The **GlazeVersion** Table is again relatively simple, a unique identifier, the version and a reference to it's parent/base glaze. e.g.

`CREATE TABLE glazeversions (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, version TEXT, glazebase_ref INTEGER)`

The **Indgredients** table is yet again simple, a unique id and name e.g.

`CREATE TABLE ingredients (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ingredient TEXT)`

The **Recipes** table would have a reference to the glazeversion (and therefore implicitly the glaze), a reference to the ingredient and a field for the amount of the ingredient e.g.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes (glazeversion_ref INTEGER, ingredient_ref INTEGER, amount INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(glazeversion_ref, ingredient_ref))`

So lets assume we have 3 base glazes RED, GREEN and BLUE. There would be 3 entries in the **glazes** table (with for illustrative purposes id's 1 2 and 3).

Also lets assume that each has three versions named Version001, Version002 and Version003 (9 rows in the glazeversion table id's 1-9 for illustrative purposes).

The resultant glazeversions table could be :-

[image]

A query could be written to show the links/associations/references e.g.

`SELECT * FROM glazeversions JOIN glazes WHERE glazebase_ref = glazes._id ORDER BY glazename`

the result would be :-

[image]

For the **Ingredients table** lets assume that there are 5 ingredients, Ochre, Calcium, Atmosphere, Temperature (temp for short) and Duration (id's 1-5 respectively). e.g.

[image]

Now it's onto the **Recipes** table, let's initially assume 1 recipe for glaze Blue version Version001 and it has 3 ingredients Atmosphere, Temp and Ochre

The recipes table would have 3 rows all three referencing the glazeversion Version001 for glaze Blue (_id 2) but each referencing the respective ingredient (id's 1, 3 and 4).

We'll also assume two other glazes:-

- Red Version001 with 4 ingredients Duration, Temp, Atmosphere and Ochre so 4 rows all referencing glazeversion Version001 for Red (_id 1), respective ingredients id's 1, 3, 4 and 5.
- Green Version003 with 2 ingredients Ochre and Calcium. So both rows reference glazeversion Version003 for Blue (_id 9), repective ingredients are id's 1 and 2.

So the table looks like:-

[image]

The following query is an example of tying everything together:-

`SELECT glazename, version, ingredient, amount FROM recipes JOIN ingredients ON ingredient_ref = ingredients._id JOIN glazeversions ON glazeversion_ref = glazeversions._id JOIN glazes ON glazebase_ref = glazes._id`

This would result in :-

[image]

If you wanted just glaze Green Version003 then you could add a WHERE clause along the lines of:-

`SELECT glazename, version, ingredient, amount FROM recipes JOIN ingredients ON ingredient_ref = ingredients._id JOIN glazeversions ON glazeversion_ref = glazeversions._id JOIN glazes ON glazebase_ref = glazes._id WHERE glazeversions._id = 9`

which would result in :-

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton dude. I didn't expect this extensive of a response for my minor problem. I've never used databases before, so implementing this solution is a bit above my skill level. But, this explains a lot of further questions I'll probably have, and I'll definitely refer back to this. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add multiple glazes that have the same identifier (say name for example), and for each one add the relevant information as well as a date. Then when you choose to view a glaze, you pull down all the info for a glaze with that identifier, and sort by the date.

Really the only extra thing you would be adding is another date, id, and name. Otherwise the entry holds all the same data you would otherwise need.